# Using Jackson annotations how can I get a separate JSON row for field and value in the output JSON?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am calling a web service that requires data sent to it to be in the form

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "field": "Pol_OwnerName",
      "value": "Policy Owner Name Here"
    },
    {
      "field": "Pol_Number",
      "value": "123456789"
    ]
}
```

I'm working with a POJO and using the `@JsonProperty` annotations:

```
@JsonProperty("Pol_OwnerName")
private String policyOwnerName;

@JsonProperty("Pol_Number")
private String policyNumber;
```

This results in the output being in the form:

```
{ 
     "Pol_OwnerName":"Policy Owner Name Here"
}
```

How would I get my values into the desired format using Jackson annotations?

Comment: Could you please share full class? I think you would need to have a field with `@JsonProperty("data")` which will point to a class containing  policyOwnerName and policyNumber as fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would need to have separate POJOs for your request. You would need to convert contents of Policy class to match the desired request. You can create a simple `WebServiceRequest` class like this:

```java
public class WebServiceRequest {
    @JsonProperty("data")
    private List<WebServiceRequestDataEntry> data;

    public List<WebServiceRequestDataEntry> getData() { return data; }

    public void setData(List<WebServiceRequestDataEntry> data) { this.data = data; }
}
```

This would contain an array of `WebServiceRequestDataEntry` elements which would look like this:

```java
public class WebServiceRequestDataEntry {
    @JsonProperty("field")
    private String field;
    @JsonProperty("value")
    private String value;

    public WebServiceRequestDataEntry(String field, String value) {
        this.field = field;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getField() { return field; }

    public void setField(String field) { this.field = field; }

    public String getValue() { return value; }

    public void setValue(String value) { this.value = value; }
}
```

You can then try converting your Policy class contents to your request payload. I'm assuming your class looks like this:

```java
private static class Policy {
    private final String policyOwnerName;
    private final String policyNumber;

    public Policy(String ownerName, String number) {
        this.policyOwnerName = ownerName;
        this.policyNumber = number;
    }

    public String getPolicyOwnerName() { return this.policyOwnerName; }

    public String getPolicyNumber() { return this.policyNumber; }
}
```

I tested it with this code and it seemed to be working as expected:

```java
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
WebServiceRequest webServiceRequest = new WebServiceRequest();

Policy[] policies = new Policy[] { new Policy("User1", "12345")};

List<WebServiceRequestDataEntry> data = new ArrayList<>();
for (Policy p : policies) {
    data.add(new WebServiceRequestDataEntry("Pol_OwnerName", p.getPolicyOwnerName()));
    data.add(new WebServiceRequestDataEntry("Pol_Number", p.getPolicyNumber()));
}
webServiceRequest.setData(data);

System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(webServiceRequest));
```

This prints the following output:

```
{"data":[{"field":"Pol_OwnerName","value":"User1"},{"field":"Pol_Number","value":"12345"}]}
```